# React native toolbar comes below the status bar

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I currently have a toolbar -

I want the green color toolbar on my statusbar and on the left side I need the back button. Here is my code -

```
<View style={{ height: 24 }} >
                <StatusBar backgroundColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)" translucent />
                <Toolbar
                    rightElement={{
                        menu: {
                            icon: "more-vert",
                            labels: ["Settings"]
                        }
                    }}
                    onRightElementPress={this.settingsShow}
                />
                <View style={styles.footer}>
                    //...
                </View>
            </View>
```

Comment: First wrap the `StatusBar` and `Toolbar` in `View` and try `<View style={{ flex:1,flexDirection: 'row',}} >` and see

Comment: No now it is coming left top corner below the white toolbar

Comment: Do you need the white toolbar? is it from the navigation? share the updated code also

Comment: I dont know where it comes from...

Comment: Here is a sample `export const Root = StackNavigator({
      Login: {
        screen: LoginStack,
      },
    },{
      mode: 'modal',
      navigationOptions: {
             header: null//Will hide header for all screens of current stack navigator, 
       },
      initialRouteName: 'Login',
    })` the `header: null` will remove the white header

Comment: Super thank you works now

Comment: If it fixed your issue, let me know. I will post as an answer so it will helpful to others @Julia

Comment: Yes sure it helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the White header from navigation, follow this sample one

```
export const Root = StackNavigator({ 
    Login: { 
      screen: LoginStack, 
     }, 
   },
    { mode: 'modal', 
      navigationOptions: { 
        header: null//Will hide header for all screens of current stack navigator, }, 
        initialRouteName: 'Login', 
    })
```